# Last item cut off in ListView

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

I have ParallaxScrollView which contain two ListViews and also TextViews it's working fine in all the devices but In Tablet(croma CRXT1125Q)the last item cut off in the first ListView, I have made the Tablet layout also but i didn't got any succeed. Please guyz help to solve it.
Help will be appreciate.

My xml looks like as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <cutomView.ParallaxScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:parallax_factor="1.9">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardAmount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorGreyBackground"
                android:elevation="@dimen/viewmargin"
                card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                card_view:contentPaddingLeft="@dimen/negContentPadding"
                card_view:contentPaddingRight="@dimen/negContentPadding"
                card_view:contentPaddingTop="@dimen/negContentPadding">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relPackagePhoto"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgPackage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/mTranspherentView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@drawable/trending_gradient_shape" />

                        <cutomView.TextViewAvenirMedium
                            android:id="@+id/txtPackageName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mTranspherentView"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:padding="@dimen/small_margine"
                            android:singleLine="false"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/small_font" />

                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/mProgressBar"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_leftt"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/relPackagePhoto"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="3">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <cutomView.TextViewAvenirMedium
                                android:id="@+id/txtOutstandingAmount"
                                style="@style/CustomBlackTextView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:maxLines="2"
                                android:padding="@dimen/main_margin"
                                android:singleLine="false"
                                android:text="@string/total_due_amount"
                                android:textColor="@color/blue_text"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <cutomView.TextViewAvenirMedium
                                android:id="@+id/txtTotalAmount"
                                style="@style/CustomBlackTextView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="@dimen/main_margin"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" />
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_weight="1">

                            <cutomView.TextViewAvenirMedium
                                android:id="@+id/txtPayNow"
                                style="@style/CustomBlackTextView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:background="@drawable/darkbluebutton"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:padding="@dimen/main_margin"
                                android:text="@string/pay_now"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" />
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cardAmount"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_left"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
                card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_margin"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/main_margin"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ListView
                            android:id="@+id/listPaidPayment"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                            android:divider="@null"
                            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/small_margine"
                            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:scrollbars="none"
                            android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/viewSeperator"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/view_width"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_top_"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/main_margin"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_margin"
                            android:background="@color/darkGreyCardBg"
                            android:visibility="gone" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <cutomView.TextViewAvenirMedium
                        android:id="@+id/txtDueAmount"
                        style="@style/CustomBlackTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_left"
                        android:background="@color/footertext"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="@dimen/main_margin"
                        android:text="@string/total_due_amount"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listDuePayment"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_margin"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/main_margin"
                        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                        android:divider="@null"
                        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/small_margine"
                        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:scrollbars="none"
                        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </cutomView.ParallaxScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: a little code may help

Comment: I have updated my code